# Server_Token key access

Tags: uber-api

I have created a new app in the uber dashboard. The server token field in the auth tab shows "Please reach out to your Uber Business Development representative for server token access." There is no support email to get the access? Please help me to resolve this. Also there is no scopes in the auth tab.

Comment: I have the same issue I tried to reach them on Twitter without any luck. maybe you can try that and see if you succeed

Comment: I have the same issue. did you find any solution?

Comment: Do you have any news?